# .NET Core pass configuration section via command line

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, configuration

In appsettingsjson file i have:

```
  "DataSource": {
    "ConnectionString": "mongodb://localhost:27017",
    "DatabaseName": "Root",
    "CollectionName": "ApiLog"
  },
```

in Program.cs, i get this data like this

```
builder.Services.Configure<DatabaseSettings>(
    builder.Configuration.GetSection("DataSource"));
```

where DatabaseSettings class is;

```
    public class DatabaseSettings
    {
        public string ConnectionString { get; set; } = null!;

        public string DatabaseName { get; set; } = null!;

        public string CollectionName { get; set; } = null!;
    }
```

Then i can access instance of DatabaseSettings via dependency injection like:

```
    public class LogService
    {
        private readonly IMongoCollection<Log> _collection;

        public LogService(
            IOptions<DatabaseSettings> databaseSettings)
        {
            var mongoClient = new MongoClient(
                databaseSettings.Value.ConnectionString);

            var mongoDatabase = mongoClient.GetDatabase(
                databaseSettings.Value.DatabaseName);

            _collection = mongoDatabase.GetCollection<ElekseLog>(
                databaseSettings.Value.CollectionName);
        }
    }
```

the question is i dont want to store db info in appsettings json file. I want to pass tis info from command line without changing the code. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to "flatten" the parameters by joining "path elements" with `:` and pass as key-value pairs. For example:

```bash
yourapp "DataSource:ConnectionString"="mongodb://localhost:27017"
```

Or

```bash
yourapp  --DataSource:ConnectionString=mongodb://localhost:27017
```

Some info can be found in the docs - [Command-line configuration provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration-providers#command-line-configuration-provider).

Comment: Thanks! How can I pass this configuration from IIS?

Comment: @yılmaz sorry, a bit late but maybe useful - you might need to check out the IIS enviroinment variables and set data by using them, note that `:`  should be replaced with two `_` in the variable name, i.e. - `DataSource:ConnectionString` -> `DataSource__ConnectionString`