# Override nested appsettings configuration with command line argument shorthand switch

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

In my application I am using appsettings to load my configuration. I have the `appsettings.json`:

```json
{
  "FileReader": {
    "InputDirectory": "tmp"
  }
}
```

I would like to have the option to override the value of `InputDirectory` with a command line argument shorthand switch (e.g. `-i`). I know I can override it via an environment variable named `FileReader__InputDirectory`, but for the SwitchMappings in my `Program.cs` I don't know what value would work. Here is my code:

```cs
IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, builder) =>
    {
        builder
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, false)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{context.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", true, false)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .AddCommandLine(source =>
            {
                source.Args = args;
                source.SwitchMappings = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                {
                    { "-i", "FileReader__InputDirectory" } // <-- what is the correct mapping here?
                };
            });
    })
    .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(context.Configuration.GetSection("FileReader")["InputDirectory"]);
        services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
    })
    .Build();
```

When I am running `dotnet run -i ./source/json` I would expect the printed out value to be **source/json** (the value from the argument) but what I get is **tmp** (the value from the `appsettings.json` file).

If I try this without the nesting with a property on the appsettings root level it works just fine.

Comment: What you ask is the default behavior. You only need to specify the *correct* key that includes the entire setting path. The host already sets up configuration to load settings from JSON, environment variables and CLI arguments, with later sources overriding previous ones.

Comment: For CLI arguments you need a switch mapping to tell which shorthand (in my case `-i`) overrides which configuration value. I know about the override structure, but I do not know how to set it up, that `-i` overrides the correct value.

Comment: The title didn't ask how to change the mapping, only how to override settings from the CLI. If you want to build your own CLI arguments a **far** better option is to use the [CommandLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/commandline/) package and provide commands, options, arguments, help, defaults etc. The CLI configuration provider is built to override config settings, not create a nice CLI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `:` as delimiter:

```cs
source.SwitchMappings = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
     { "-i", "FileReader:InputDirectory" } 
};
```

`__` is substitution for `:` specifically for environment variables.

Note that you can just pass it via CLI parameter ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75173633/2501279)):

```
dotnet run --FileReader:InputDirectory=./source/json
```

See also:

- [Configuration in .NET: Binding hierarchies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration#binding-hierarchies)
- [Environment variable configuration provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration-providers#environment-variable-configuration-provider):

  > The `:` delimiter doesn't work with environment variable hierarchical keys on all platforms. For example, the `:` delimiter is not supported by Bash. The double underscore (`__`), which is supported on all platforms, automatically replaces any `:` delimiters in environment variables.
- [`System.CommandLine`](https://github.com/dotnet/command-line-api) to perform parameter parsing

Answer (score 1):

It seems the real question is how to add a new argument mapping, not how to override settings.

All config sources are available through the [ConfigurationBuilder.Sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.iconfigurationbuilder.sources?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) list. The configuration code could find the existing source and change its mapping :

```
.ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, builder) =>
{
    var cliSource=builder.Sources.OfType<CommandLineConfigurationSource>();
    if(cliSource!=null)
    {
        cliSource.SwitchMappings=new Dictionary<string, string>()
                {
                    { "-i", "FileReader:InputDirectory" }
                };
    }
}
```

---

Remove the entire `ConfigureAppConfiguration` section and use `--FileReader:InputDirectory` in the command line to override the JSON setting.

```
dotnet run --FileReader:InputDirectory=tmp
```

The generic host configures JSON, environment variables *and* CLI arguments out of the box. There's no need to add the same sources all over again.

The [Command Line arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#command-line-arguments) section in ASP.NET Core configuration shows how to pass arguments using various delimiters like `--`, `=` or `/`, eg :

```
dotnet run /MyKey "Using /" /Position:Title=Cmd /Position:Name=Cmd_Rick
```

or

```
dotnet run --MyKey "Using --" --Position:Title=Cmd --Position:Name=Cmd_Rick
```

In your case, you can use

```
dotnet run --FileReader:InputDirectory=tmp
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My question was more specific towards the shorthand configuration (`-i` in the example). I updated the title to make it more clear.

Comment: The question asked how to override settings, not the mapping. I suspect you can change the mapping *without* having to specify all sources again. The CLI config provider wasn't built to create usable CLIs though, only to override settings. If you want a nice CLI, with help, descriptions, defaults etc you should check one of the many CLI packages, including System.CommandLine

Comment: @DanielLerps you should be able to add switch mappings to the existing CommandLineConfigurationSource instead of adding it again